# "private" directory not accessible in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

The directory `private` lives under my DocumentRoot, and despite its name, it should be accessible just like any other dir. But if I add the following `RewriteRule` to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Apache returns 403 for http://server/private/2201. The error log states

```
client denied by server configuration: /private/2201.html
```

If I then rename `private` to `foo`, or if I request 2201.html directly, the file is served:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2011:10:24:45 +0100] "GET /private/2201 HTTP/1.1" 403 214
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2011:10:24:58 +0100] "GET /foo/2201 HTTP/1.1" 200 3068
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Nov/2011:10:27:39 +0100] "GET /private/2201.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3068
```

This is confusing. Is there any special rule for directories named `private`? If so – why does the direct request for 2201.html work (although the denied request seems to handle the same resource, at least according to the error log entry)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an embarrassing case of RTM. Apache's documentation regarding [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) explicitly states that substitution strings "will be treated as a URL-path unless a directory named www exists at the root or your file-system, in which case it will be treated as a file-system path", at least when defining a RewriteRule outside a directory context.

Since my filesystem contains `/private`, but not `/foo`, and the URL `/private/2212.html` is not affected by the RewriteRule, the pattern above should be expected.

The solution was to add the flag [[PT]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) (passthrough) to my RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into Apache or mod_rewrite that makes the name `private` special, AFAIK.  But, your configuration might have come with a default rule that treats that name differently.  Try grepping your configuration for the word `private`, e.g.

```
grep private /etc/httpd/httpd.conf  # RedHat, CentOS
grep -r private /etc/apache2        # Debian, Ubuntu, etc.
```

If you find a RewriteRule that matches, that's your culprit.

Your log entries make clear that it's the name `private` in particular that's causing the problem, and that it must be a RewriteRule that's causing the request to be denied.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that, and the string "private" occurs only as part of a path name for ErrorLog, CustomLog, TypesConfig directives. If I remove the Order directive, by the way, the error changes from 403 to 404 for http://server/private/2201. Very strange.